# JQuery select part of paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

if i have this html code:

```
<p id='ppp'>first part <b id='bbb'>something bold</b> second part <b>...</b></p>
```

how to reference (select) "second part", with js / JQuery.

Comment: `document.getElementById("ppp").lastChild.data` https://jsfiddle.net/z1uwwg1y/ It would be better if you show exactly how far you've gotten. We don't know precisely what you don't know how to do.

Comment: There could be several possible ways to do this, but you need to provide more specifics on what you're trying to accomplish if you want the best answer.

Comment: @squint, i will test it, but isn't bbb last and only child of ppp. or ppp has 3 childs???

Comment: MetNP: `ppp` has 3 child nodes. The `.lastChild` is a textNode that holds the text you want.

Comment: @squint, thanks, this works very well. i did'nt know that first part and second part becomes separate nodes EVEN they are not inside OWN tags. maybe you should write something about it as an answer. It is little bit confusing...

Comment: @squint, sorry i have one more request, ... to reference it by bbb (as first child after bbb, not as last)

Comment: MetNP: I'll add that to my answer below. It is viewed as the `.nextSibling` from the perspective of `bbb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note, the question has changed so that the targeted text node is no longer the last child of `ppp`.*

---

In your case, you have an Element node that has the id `ppp`. That Element has 3 child nodes: a text node, followed by an Element with the id `bbb`, followed by another text node.

```
Element#ppp --+
              |
              0--TextNode ("first part ")
              |
              1--Element#bbb --+
              |                |
              |                0--TextNode ("something bold")
              |
              2--TextNode (" second part")
```

One way of fetching the data you want would be to select the `ppp` Element by ID, and then use the `.lastChild` property of the Element to get the text node you're targeting.

```
document.getElementById("ppp").lastChild.data
```

Text nodes have a `.data` (or `.nodeValue`) property that can be used to get its text content as a `string`, so the above code will give the actual text you want.

---

If it's more convenient to target the `bbb` Element, then use `.nextSibling` to grab the text node that comes *after* the `bbb` Element.

```
document.getElementById("bbb").nextSibling.data
```

Comment: Thanks, i only did not know that when you insert <b>something</b> inside text, left and right becomes separate childs, which is good.

Comment: @MetNP: Yes, everything (even HTML comments) is represented in a nice, orderly tree structure, so it's pretty easy to traverse and get whatever you need.